# Angular2 RC6 Inject LOCALE_ID fails after bundling

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, rollupjs

I am trying to bundle an Angular2 app, just updated to RC6, based loosely on [this excellent blog post.](http://blog.mgechev.com/2016/06/26/tree-shaking-angular2-production-build-rollup-javascript/)

I have a Pipe that only wraps the built-in DatePipe with the difference that it accepts a null argument and does something in the case that it receives that.  For RC6, this had to be updated to pass the `_locale` argument to DatePipe.  Here is the pipe:

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform, Inject, LOCALE_ID} from '@angular/core';
import {DatePipe} from '@angular/common';

@Pipe({
    name: 'myDate',
})
export class MyDatePipe implements PipeTransform {
    constructor(@Inject(LOCALE_ID) private _locale: string){}

    transform(value: any, pattern?: string): string {
        if (value === null) {
            return 'Not Available';
        }

        return new DatePipe(this._locale).transform(value, pattern);
    }
}
```

This method of dependency injection is identical to the [one used by the built-in DatePipe (best I can tell).](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/dd03bf12e1c035597d2fab252e393846efca5ea1/modules/%40angular/common/src/pipes/date_pipe.ts#L98)

When compiled for development and loaded with systemjs, this works fine.  But after bundling with rollup, `_locale` is `null` when passed to the constructor.  The instantiation in the bundle looks like this:

```
this._pipe_myDate_0 = new MyDatePipe(this.parentInjector.get(LOCALE_ID));
// this.parentInjector.get(LOCALE_ID) == null
```

I can provide rollup config and tsconfigs if that is helpful - but will hold off for now, since it will add a lot of bulk to the question.  The bundling process right now is:

```
ngc(es2015) -> rollup(es2015) -> tsc(es5)
```

The rest of the app is working great!  I have worked around the issue for now by passing `'en-US'` to DatePipe directly, but I am curious about why it's not working, and I would like to do it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compile for for each locale:

```
ngc --locale=en-US
```

Comment: Are you suggesting that it's just not working because the default locale doesn't compile correctly?

Comment: Correct. When I compile it without the locale option the injected _locale is null! I use the final 2.0.0 release